# Trying to add custom prefixes to my discord.py bot using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

This is my code:

```py
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM prefijos WHERE id = ?', (message.guild.id,))
    prefix = cursor.fetchone()
    db.commit()
    return when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

But this code doesn't works as expected. It's only work when I mention the bot, but not with the custom prefix. As I said, I'm using sqlite3 as the database where I store the prefixes.

The error that I'm having (when I use the prefix) it's this:

```py
    raise TypeError("Iterable command_prefix or list returned from get_prefix must "
TypeError: Iterable command_prefix or list returned from get_prefix must contain only strings, not tuple
```

And If I delete the comma from the "cursor.execute..." part, this error appears (it's an error from sqlite)

```
    cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM prefijos WHERE id = ?', (message.guild.id))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

How I can fix this code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.fetchone()` returns a list or tuple, even if the row only contains one thing.  Try

```
prefix=cursor.fetchone()[0]
```